# Trigger with subtracting dates

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

Hey Guys last trigger of the semester here! This one is very confusing for me. I need to add a 2 dollar late fee for each day a video is returned late (transaction table) then update the unpaid balance on the members table with that late fee. This is what I got so far, but it does not like the subtraction sign by the dates. Any help or suggestions would be great specially with the subtracting of dates properly to get a number.

Edit: After some suggestions this is what I have now I am getting these errors

```
Create or Replace Trigger Late_Rule
BEFORE INSERT ON Transaction
For each Row
DECLARE

Fee Number;

BEGIN

Select Date_Due, Date_Returned 
From Transaction;

If new.Date_Returned > new.Date_Due
THEN 
Fee := (new.Date_Returned - new.Date_Due) * 2;


END IF;

Update Member
    Set Unpaid_Bal = Unpaid_Bal + Fee;
end;
/
show error;
```

7/1  PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
10/1  PL/SQL: Statement ignored
10/4  PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.DATE_RETURNED' must be declared

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a value to a result of a subtraction (an lvalue) - you need to assign it to a variable.

EDIT:
The assignment operator in pl/sql is `:=`, not `=`:

```
Create or Replace Trigger Late_Rule
BEFORE INSERT ON Transaction
For each Row
DECLARE

ChargeDays Number;
Fee Number;

BEGIN

If new.Date_Returned > new.Due_Date 
THEN 
Fee := (new.Date_Returned - new.Due_Date) * 2;

ELSE 
Fee := 0

END IF;

Update Member
    Where Unpaid_Bal = Unpaid_Bal + Fee;
end;
/
show error;
```

Comment: Ok Thanks I tried it out an got this error PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the f ollowing: := . ( @ % ;     Ill keep going at it to see if I can fix it

Comment: I got 3 more errors dealing with the END LINE/COL  ERROR  
15/1  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following: * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like LIKE2_ LIKE4_ LIKEC_ between || multiset member SUBMULTISET_ The symb ol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.  
18/5  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WHERE" when expecting one of t he following: . @ <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited- identifier> partition set subpartition  
19/1  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END"

Comment: Yes, this semicolon is not needed `Fee := (new.Date_Returned - new.Due_Date) * 2;` because it is part of the `IF-THEN-ELSE` statement. Also, the update syntax is not right.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

In your example it would be:

```
...
THEN DATEDIFF ( dd , new.Date_Returned , new.Due_Date )
```

Where `dd` stands for day.

Comment: Where would I put this would it just be DATEDIFF ( dd , new.Date_Returned , new.Due_Date ) * 2  ?

Comment: might be a dumb question but do I have to declare DATEDIFF?

Comment: You don't have to declare it, it is a built in function. You could absolutely do DATEDIFF ( dd , new.Date_Returned , new.Due_Date ) * 2

Comment: Oh no, I wrote this for T-SQL, is it PL-SQL?

Comment: I am so sorry!  I hope your assignment goes really well.